# Converting a string to a double, then pushing it to a vector in a While Loop

Tags: c++, string, vector, double

```
vector<double> data;
string content;
ifstream infile;
infile.open("test.txt");
   while(getline(infile, content, ' '))
{
     atof(content.c_str());
     data.push_back(content);
}
infile.close();
```

So here I'm taking strings from a text file and trying to store them into a vector as doubles. However I get the error that it can't push 'content' into the data vector because it isn't a double. I've tried a couple things and get the same general error that content isn't being converted to a double. So im not sure if I haven't noticed a simple error because tunnel vision or if there's something else that I'm missing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code doesn't store the return value of `atof`. Also you could just do `double d; while (infile >> d) {..}`

Comment: Depending on your library support there's also `std::stod`. You could simply use `>>` to read the double straight from the stream as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atof` returns the `double`, so this line

```
atof(content.c_str());
```

simply discards the result. You can do it like this:

```
double tmp = atof(content.c_str());
data.push_back(tmp);
```

or without a temporary

```
data.push_back(atof(content.c_str()));
```

Idiomatic way of reading a file into a vector in C++ is as follows:

```
back_insert_iterator< vector<double> > back_it(data);
copy(istream_iterator<double>(infile)
,   istream_iterator<double>()
,   back_it);
```

This uses `std::copy` function along with an input iterator and a push back iterator to hide the loop. When you can combine vector declaration and reading from file, you can shorten this even further:

```
vector<double> data(istream_iterator<double>(cin), (istream_iterator<double>())); // C++98 syntax
```

or

```
vector<double> data { istream_iterator<double>(cin), istream_iterator<double>() }; // C++11 syntax
```

The C++98 syntax uses an extra pair of parentheses to subvert the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: ...or just `ifstream infile("test.txt"); vector<double> data{istream_iterator<double>(infile), istream_iterator<double>()};`

Comment: That was it, I had forgotten that I needed to use a temp value, so it makes much more sense now why that was the problem. I really appreciate yours and everyone else help.